# A C# SDK for LinkedIn

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, linkedin-api

I was wondering if there is a SDK for LinkedIn in C#. I have found similar SDKs for Facebook and Twitter, but so far no luck with LinkedIn.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/using-linkedin-api-c-windows-forms-app)

Comment: take a look at this LinkedIn developer [link](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1230), see if it is what you are wanting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are libraries and tools with sample code.  Some are old but it will probably get you started.

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools

Comment: Thanks. Is there any one in particular you prefer to use? I mean usually one of the libraries is better to work with. Thanks again.

Comment: I haven't used any of them, but this is where I would start.

Answer (score 1):

You can this article - based on `HttpWebRequest`, fix REST endoint, and treat the response

You have a quick-start guide to the resources available via the LinkedIn API

Link : http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1258

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections/");  

using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)  
{  
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is any example demonstrate how to make REST API Share in linkedIn ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use their REST services as shown in [this](http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2011/10/15/deep-dive-into-the-linkedin-api-use-c-to-search-for-your-dream-job-writing-c.aspx) example.

I found an open source toolkit at http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/